# Deserialize Breeze JObject into EntityInfo without saving changes

Tags: breeze

I have a breeze controller that accepts a JObject, is there an easy way to deserialize that JObject into it's strongly typed source EntityInfo objet without going through Save changes / Before Save changes. I just want to get the object that the JObject payload is referring to.
Thanks for your help.

I ended up using the approach outlined in this related question.
[Uninitialised JsonSerializer in Breeze SaveBundleToSaveMap sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691579/uninitialised-jsonserializer-in-breeze-savebundletosavemap-sample)

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1

Take a look at the code in the Breeze.ContextProvider class's [**CreateEntityInfoFromJson**](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net/blob/master/Breeze.ContextProvider/ContextProvider.cs#L221-L237) method.  It's protected-internal so you'll need to copy the code or call it using reflection.  *Use at your own risk*.

---

### Option 2

The breeze savechanges code uses a public class called `SaveWorkState` which is constructed using two arguments:  a `ContextProvider` and a `JArray`.  To get an idea of what's expected for the 
`JArray`, take a look at the "entities" property in the JSON sent to the server during a savechanges.

Once the `SaveWorkState` is constructed you can access the `EntityInfo` objects via the `EntityInfoGroups` property.

---

*I've never tried either option before, found these options by looking at the [breeze.server.net](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net) code.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible ... and pretty easy too. I answered this question in GREAT detail on the related SO question, [Uninitialised JsonSerializer in Breeze SaveBundleToSaveMap sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691579/uninitialised-jsonserializer-in-breeze-savebundletosavemap-sample) that you referenced.